# C++ Function specialization not allowed?

Tags: c++, templates, specialization

Here is a very simple example of function specialization in C++. I think it should work but Visual Studio's compiler give me an ambiguity message.

```
template <class T> T min(T a, T b) { 
    if(a < b) return a;
    else return b;
}

string min(string str1, string str2) { 
    if(str1.length() < str2.length()) return str1;
    return str2;
}


void main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int n=12, p=15;
    string str1= "monsieur", str2= "bonjour" ;

    cout << min(n,p) << endl;           
    cout << min(str1, str2) << endl;
}
```

In fact it says that "min(n, p) is ambigous and don't know which function to call. It is probably a trivial problem but I haven't figured out the problem. I tried the following headers too:

```
template<> string min(string str1, string str2)
```

and:

```
template<> string min<string>(string str1, string str2)
```

Can someone help me out?

Comment: Tell us the exact error messages and which lines they are referring to (otherwise we can only guess, since your example code is probably not quite minimal).

Comment: Using min as a name will probably cause trouble as well, try something like 'blah' first that won't clash with standard identifiers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A non-template which doesn't require a conversion is always the better match. That is, if these were the only definitions of `min()`, there would be no problem (i.e. renaming the function `min` to something else would remove the ambiguity). The ambiguity is between `template <typename T> T const& std::min(T const&, T const&)` and you templatized version. Another fix is to remove the using declaration and explicitly qualify names from namespace `std`, i.e. the following code compiles fine:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template <class T> T min(T a, T b) { 
    return a < b? a: b;
}

std::string min(std::string str1, std::string str2) { 
    return str1.length() < str2.length()? str1: str2;
}    

int main()
{
    int n=12, p=15;
    std::string str1= "monsieur", str2= "bonjour" ;

    std::cout << min(n,p) << "\n";           
    std::cout << min(str1, str2) << "\n";
}
```

Please note that the `std::string` version of your `min()` is **not** a specialization but an overload! When calling the function as you did this doesn't matter and it will choose the version as expected. However, when calling the function while explicitly specifying the template argument it will not:

```
min(str1, str2);              // calls string overload
min<std::string>(str1, str2); // calls the function template (*)
```

(*) Actually, `min<std::string>(str1, str2)` is, again, ambiguous with the version from namespace `std` due to argument dependent look up; if it were named differently it would call the template version.

If you wanted to really specialize the function, you would write something like this:

```
template <> std::string min<std::string>(std::string, std::string) { ... }
```

That said, here are few random notes on the program unrelated to the ambiguity and the specialization:

- In C++ `main()` **always** has to be declared to return a `int`. It is allowed to omit the return statement in `main()` but some compilers don't get that right. For portable code you're best off to use a return of `int` and just return `0` (or `EXIT_SUCCESS declared in <stdlib.h>).`
- You almost certainly want to pass these arguments by `const` reference: copying strings isn't that expensive, especially for small `std::string`s (because contemporary `std::string` implementations seem to use the small string optimization) but it isn't free either. If the objects are reasonably big it can be a performance problem.
- I assume that this is just a test to play with overloading/specialization. Otherwise, the `std::string` version of `min()` is ill-advised because it behaves in unexpected ways.
- your test strings are badly chosen because they wouldn't show that the overload/specialization is actually used.
- `std::endl` is grossly overused and does something different than most people think it does: in addition to inserting a newline character ('\n') it also flushes the std::ostream. It is the latter part which comes as a surprise and I found that it creates major performance problems quite frequently. Unless you really intend to flush the stream, just write a \n.

Comment: Very impressed by your answer! Thanks I learned a lot of things!

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is likely due to conflicting definitions of `min` somewhere else (probably the standard library). Try renaming your function to `my_min` or something else.

Changing the name of the function made your example compile correctly for me.

Comment: Can believe that was the problem. Thank you and sorry for having disturbed peoples for such a trivial matter.

Comment: No worries. Ideally, more than one person will learn something from this question!